# How to use relative paths in twig files in S3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, twig, relative-path

I keep all my twig files on remote s3 and load them with custom loader. But I faced a problem with such approach - relative paths(for example ../css/app.css) dont work properly. Twig tries to to locate file on my server, not on s3. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: just use an absolute path?

Comment: @DarkBee I'd like to,but that's not possible, I need only relative paths in this case

Comment: Why would that not be possible?